# The meaning of "undermine his image as..."

Tags: phrase-meaning

"But he did nothing publicly to undermine his image as Beelzebub or Mephistopheles..."

Does it mean that he never makes himself look like Beelzebub or Mephistopheles in the public?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. On the contrary, the person concerned is making no attempt to discourage the impression that they are behaving in a way that encourages them being likened to the two descriptions. 'Does nothing to undermine' means they are not attempting to undo the impression they are giving.

Comment: An incomplete sentence does not help much. But as Nigel mentioned, "to undermine someone's image" means to act in a way that harms its public view (reputation).

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I got it wrong because I thought "as" in this sentence was a preposition for "undermine".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shamelessly stolen from @Nigel J.

Welcome to EL&U.

> On the contrary, the person concerned is making no attempt to discourage the impression that they are behaving in a way that encourages them being likened to the two descriptions.'Does nothing to undermine' means they are not attempting to undo the impression they are giving.